# passing 'self' to other function in twisted tcp server

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

In the following code I have twisted server as well as twisted scheduler which calls a function every time after fixed interval of time, the job of that function is to send data to every client. Following is my code

```
class Echo(LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        self.setRawMode()
        startClock(self)
        print 'Connected Client', self._peer

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
       self.factory.clients.remove(self)
       print 'Lost connection from', self._peer

    def rawDataReceived(self, data):
       inputArray = ["%02X"%ord(inp) for inp in data]
       if(CheckPacket(inputArray)):
            PacketParser(inputArray, self)
       else:
           print "Fail"
           d = self.transport.getHost ()
           print d.type

l = task.LoopingCall(partial(sendTimeRequest,self))
l.start(660.0)

def sendTimeRequest(self):
    sendString2 = ''.join(SendPacketList)
    try:
       for client in self.factory.clients:
           client.transport.write(binascii.unhexlify(sendString2))
    except Exception, ex1:
       print ex1
def main():
    port = 8000
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    factory.clients = []
    try:
        reactor.listenTCP(port,factory)
    except Exception, ex:
        print "Port %d is busy: %s" % (port, ex)
    reactor.run()
```

Thus my question is that how can I pass 'self' to the function(sendTimeRequest) twisted scheduler is calling?

Comment: Your question should be: how do I pass the `Echo-object` that is named `self` in the functions `connectionMade`, `connectionLost`, `rawDataReceived` to the function `sendTimeRequest`. Part of the answer: after it is created.